# commands "time 1:10" "echo %time%" returns 1:09

Tags: batch-file

My batch script does the following 15 times in a row.

```
time 1:10 
echo %time%
```

the results returns 1:09. I have tried this with milliseconds and its exactly one millisecond behind. How is this possible?

Comment: @ ken I expect it to set my clock time to 1:10, which it did

Comment: @KenWhite I am on windows. time 1:10 changes the clock in my system tray to 1:10. immediate after that echo %time% returns 1:09:99.99, so Yes it set the time properly, but the following echo should return 1:10, it does not.

Comment: Why should a subsequent call to TIME return 1:10? Do you think time stands still?

Comment: I'd expect a call to `time` after the time is set to return a value _after_ the time that it is set to...

Comment: exactly  so 1:11 would be great, why is it returning one less 1:09

Answer (score 2):

It is because CMD.EXE expands %time% before it executes the command(s). The following will give you the result you expect:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
time 1:10
echo !time!
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "expands" %time%

Comment: @sncSoftware - it replaces the string `%time%` with the value of the `%time%` variable.

Comment: To reiterate what SomethingDark says, the variable `%time%` is replaced with the value of the variable - the actual time. This occurs when the batch file is first read by CMD.EXE, but _before_ any of the commands are executed. Sometime later the commands are executed, but the value of %time% has already been determined. `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` causes the variable `time` to not be replaced with its value until the `echo` command is actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

(Theory only)

I'd suggest that what is happening is that the time being set is in fact one "tick" earlier than the time defined.

What happens then is that the time becomes "as defined" when the next "tick" occurs.

The time at which the next "tick" occurs is anything from one-nanosecond (directly after the time has been set) to one "tick" later (ie a tick occured just before the time was set)

If the time was **not** set this way, then reading the time directly after setting it would randomly say (the-time-set) or (the-time-set+1 tick) depending on how soon after setting the reading was actually performed. Of course, if it **is** set this way, then it would randomly say (the-time-set - 1 tick) or (the-time-set)...

So - how long is a tick? Suppose it is 1ms (intuitively makes sense) then the displayed time is in centicesonds, so truncated it's *.99 sec

I question the assertion **echo %time% returns 1:09:99.99**. I'm more inclined to believe **1:09:59.99**

As I say, only a theory...

Comment: So the processor is pre caching the commands, why is it not read in order? There shouldn't be anything "random" about this. Unless you know something about CPU cache I don't..

Comment: First: set time to (requested - 1 tick) Next: echo time = 1:09:59:99 Then a timer tick occurs and sets time=1:10 as requested. No change in sequence. The random part occurs in that the time at which any of the actions take place is random with respect to the time that a tick is counted. It may be 1uSec later, it may be 1mSec; all depends on which combination of interrupts  may be happening and how long `cmd` takes to interpret and execute instructions. For instance, `cmd` will take marginally longer to complete `set /a x=1` than `set      /a x=1000`, and all thise extra cycles add up.

Comment: so this situation only occurred in one of 3 CPUs I tested. I'll test more and post results / model